# What version of twitter bootstrap should I use for Grails 1.3.6

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, grails, responsive-design

we currently have a grails 1.3.6 application and we're planning to make it responsive via twitter bootstrap. Does twitter bootstrap support grails 1.3.6? Because I cant find one here: http://grails.org/plugin/twitter-bootstrap. Do you recommend manually downloading boostrap source files from getbootstrap.com instead? what is the difference between this and the grails plugin?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the fact the plugin requires 1.3.7+ you won't be able to use it in 1.3.6. So, you're left with downloading the source and manually including it in your application. Any version of bootstrap (not the plugin) would be acceptable to use with your Grails project.

The plugin does provide more than just the assets for bootstrap. It also fixes the markup for the `<g:paginate>` tag to be compatible with bootstrap.